# How to create a custom facet for a Time range for an SXA search filter

Tags: sxa, azure-search, search-facet

I have a search result component showing all the events.
The requirement is to add a CheckList filter to filter the events that have their event date before 9AM and after 9AM.

How can I create a custom facet to achieve this extending `ISimpleFacet`?

Answer (score 1):

I could be wrong but I don't think implementing ISimpleFacet is the way to go for your situation. If anyone knows how to do it that way, that would be a great other answer.

But to solve your issue, you could also create an extra (custom) field in the sxa index. That field could contain your logic and have a value indicating whether the event was before or after 9AM - if that are the only options a boolean would be sufficient.

I you don't know how to create such an extra field, google is your best friend. Search for `ComputedIndexField` and you will find code and config examples. The code is similar across the different Sitecore versions - the configuration will differ between versions and is also dependent on the search provider (solr, azure search).

Your code will be something like:

```
public class MyComputedField : IComputedIndexField
{
    public object ComputeFieldValue(IIndexable indexable)
    {
        return (....  < 9AM);
            
    }
}
```

Your config could look like this (example from 9.2 and Azure):

```
<sitecore>
    <contentSearch>
      <indexConfigurations search:require="azure">
        <defaultCloudIndexConfiguration>
          <documentOptions>
            <fields hint="raw:AddComputedIndexField">
               <field fieldName="eventdatenine" returnType="bool" type="....MyComputedField, ..."/>
            </fields>
          </documentOptions>
        </defaultCloudIndexConfiguration>
      </indexConfigurations>
    </contentsearch>
</sitecore>
```

You can use such a field in a facet (use the index field name in the facet definition). If you want to use a list facet, you'd better use a string field (and not a bool) and put the values you want to have in the facet list in the index. Those values will be used by the filter component for the display.

Comment: Thanks Pal  I know how to create computed index just one query can i use the same directly in facet?And in search filter what will be displayed (usually field name gets displayed when we use the list facet with field name)

Comment: Added to the answer - put the values you want in the index (use a string field) as those will be used to display.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you should create a computed field like that.

```
public class IsBeforeNineComputedField : IComputedIndexField
{
  public override object ComputeFieldValue(IIndexable indexable)
  {
     Item item = indexable as SitecoreIndexableItem;
     var db = item.Database;
     var isCoreDb = string.Compare(item.Database.Name, "core", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0;
     if (db == null || isCoreDb)
     {
        return false;
     }
     var nineOClock  = new TimeSpan(9, 0, 0)
     return ((DateTime)item.Fields["Created"].Value).TimeOfDay < nineOClock;
   }
}
```

The config

```
<sitecore>
<contentSearch>
  <indexConfigurations search:require="azure">
    <defaultCloudIndexConfiguration>
      <documentOptions>
        <fields hint="raw:AddComputedIndexField">
           <field fieldName="isbeforenine" returnType="bool" type="Your.Namespace.IsBeforeNineComputedField, Your.Dll.Name"/>
        </fields>
      </documentOptions>
    </defaultCloudIndexConfiguration>
  </indexConfigurations>
</contentsearch>
```

A couple of auxiliary classes

```
public class FilterSearchResultItem : SearchResultItem
{
    [IndexField("isbeforenine_b")]
    public virtual string IsBeforeNine { get; set; }

    [IndexField("_latestversion")]
    public bool IsLatestVersion { get; set; }
}

public class SearchResponse
{
    public List<FilterSearchResultItem> Results { get; set; }
    public FacetCategory FacetIsBeforeNine { get; set; }
}
```

And the main search method would be more like

```
public SearchResponse GetSearchResults()
{
    using (var context = ContentSearchManager.GetIndex("sitecore_web_index").CreateSearchContext())
    {
        var query = context.GetQueryable<FilterSearchResultItem>();
        //Set the search context and check if is the last version of the item
        query = query.Where(x => x.Paths.Contains(ID.Parse("{9CCE9D90-CF8F-4210-B503-5474D48B4928}")) && x.IsLatestVersion);

        FacetCategory facet = query.FacetOn(it => it.IsBeforeNine).GetFacets().Categories.FirstOrDefault(it => it.Name.Equals("isbeforenine"));
        SearchResults<FilterSearchResultItem> searchResults = query.GetResults();
        List<FilterSearchResultItem> resultList = searchResults.Select(x => x.Document).ToList();
        return new SearchResponse
        {
            Results = resultList,
            FacetIsBeforeNine = facet
        };
    }
}
```

I
I'm doing pretty much like that in a solution using Sitecore 10.3 with SXA and JSS